# Samba: connecting to a DFS share using smbclient

Tags: linux, samba, network-share, cifs

I have a problem connecting to a DFS share using `smbclient`. It does work using `mount -t cifs`.
Namely, when I do

```
sudo mount -t cifs //<dfs-url>/<service> ~/mountpoint/ -o username=<username>
```

things work perfectly. However, doing

```
smbclient //<dfs-url>/<service> -U <username> -W <workgroup>
Enter <username>'s password:
Domain=[<domain>] OS=[Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 9600] Server=[Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 6.3]
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME
```

I would expect that if I can connect using a cifs mount, I should be able to connect using smbclient.
Am I doing something wrong with the smbclient invokation?
Has anbody managed to connect to a DFS share using smbclient?

Answer (score 2):

The error "tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME" is because the path is not correct.
Example:
Path = `//<dfs-url>/data/share1`
Path = `//<dfs-url>/data/share2`

When mounting cifs, you can mount `//<dfs-url>/data` and see both shares.
With smbclient you only can use `//<dfs-url>/data/share1` or share2

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. However, I have a path to the share under the service, but adding it does not help. I'd need to get a more helpful response from smbclient to be able to test further.